# Application freeze at connection.open()

Tags: c#, sql, firebird, sqlclient

I created a Firebird database and successfully connected to it via Visual Studio Server Explorer. Now I want to test it through code, so I made a simple form that - on a button press - changes a label text to a value from the database. Here is the code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=localhost;initial catalog=D:\\poslovanje\\POSLOVANJE.FDB;user id=SYSDBA");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM USERS", con);

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(dr.Read())
            {
                label3.Text = dr[0].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

Problem is my application just freezes when it comes to `con.Open();`

I have also tried this connection string:

```
User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=D:\\poslovanje\\poslovanje.fdb;Data Source=localhost;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's basic beginners mistake, i need to use FbConnection and FbCommand, not Sql

Comment: Post the complete "correct" code to get more upvotes.

Comment: You might also want to consider moving database access off your GUI thread

Comment: @Maarten 2 days need to pass